# android studio: the emulator cannot be launched more than once

Tags: android, android-studio

So, I have Android studio installed, and I cannot use the emulator more than once.

So once installed, the emulator works very well at the first use. when I close it, then open it again, it does not work anymore. The message reads: Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed.
Installation failed due to: 'UNKNOWN'.

I have to delete it, then install it again, for it to work again...just once.

what can be my problem please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have occured the same situation as yours, and I fixed it.

My OS is Windows 10, my experience may help.

First, find the environment variable **%ANDROID_SDK_HOME%**, as for me, the %ANDROID_SDK_HOME% is *E:\Android\Sdk*, and then find your emulator's configuration file in the path,

*%ANDROID_SDK_HOME%.android\avd\{your_emulator_name}.avd*

For me, it is *E:\Android\Sdk.android\avd\Pixel_testx64.avd*.
In this path, you will find a file named **emu-launch-params.txt**. In this file, you can see that,

```
-studio-params
C:\Users\lenovo\temp\emu.tmp
```

It is a path which Win 10 use it as default path to store temp file, and I have changed the registry, so my temp file path should be

```
-studio-params
E:\Users\lenovo\temp\emu.tmp
```

I just change it, and it works.

But every time I open the emulator, it will be the origin, so I must change this file every time I use the emulator.